# What does the highlighted vs. non-highlighted posts on Careers mean?

Tags: support, jobs

On the Careers page, there are highlighted and non-highlighted job listings. What do these mean?

[image: Careers Image]

At first I thought it was a showing what I had in my profile, but I have `jquery`, so I'd expect `A` to be highlighted. I have `java` (expecting `B` to be highlighted). I don't have anything in `C`, yet it is highlighted. I have `php` and `mysql` and `D` is highlighted. Thus, I am confused what these colors are telling me. They look like they are attempting to help me, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highlighted jobs are a paid product.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, can you explain what that means? Does that just mean they have a company page?

Comment: It means the person who purchased the job listing paid extra money to have the job highlighted blue in search results.

Comment: As this now came up again here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381546/why-are-some-job-ads-colored-differently?cb=1 I think it's a bad choice to use the same colour as is being used for watched tags. Perhaps there can be a different way to highlight some job adds that are "sponsored".